# JQuery make the scroll function execute before completing the ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make use of jQuery to scroll down to a text box on the click event.
But the scroll event takes place after the ajax call in the function happens.

```
$("#execute_btn").click(function(){

      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#scripts_execution_section").offset().top
      }, 500);

      // Ajax Synchronous call

    });
```

So It will execute the Ajax call, and only after the response it will scroll down.
How can I make it such that it will scroll down and then make the ajax call?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

In your jQuery.animate(), add last parameter callback function to be called only after the animation is done

```
$('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#scripts_execution_section").offset().top
  }, 500,function(){

       // your ajax call here
  });
```